# Debian10 boot problem when booting between external USB vs SSD

Tags: dual-boot, uefi, debian-installer

I have installed Debian 10 on an internal hdd it worked fine with UEFI secure boot.

When I installed second Debian on external USB, then it only boots from that USB.

When I unplug the USB from the laptop to boot into the SSD, it comes to error

> Minimal bash-like line editing.

Disabling secure boot didn't help.

```
Disk /dev/sda: 238,5 GiB, 256060514304 bytes, 500118192 sectors
Disk model
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 

Device       Start       End   Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sda1     2048   1050623   1048576   512M EFI System
/dev/sda2  1050624   1550335    499712   244M Linux filesystem
/dev/sda3  1550336 500117503 498567168 237,8G Linux filesystem


Disk /dev/sdb: 57,3 GiB, 61505273856 bytes, 120127488 sectors
Disk model: Ultra USB 3.0   
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 

Device       Start       End   Sectors  Size Type
/dev/sdb1     2048   1050623   1048576  512M EFI System
/dev/sdb2  1050624   1550335    499712  244M Linux filesystem
/dev/sdb3  1550336 120125439 118575104 56,6G Linux filesystem


Disk /dev/mapper/sdc3_crypt: 56,5 GiB, 60693676032 bytes, 118542336 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/mapper/usb--vg-root: 48,7 GiB, 52240056320 bytes, 102031360 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/mapper/usb--vg-swap_1: 7,9 GiB, 8451522560 bytes, 16506880 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
```

lvs output

```
LV     VG        Attr       LSize   Pool Origin Data%  Meta%  Move Log Cpy%Sync Convert
root   intern-vg -wi-a----- 229,80g                                                    
swap_1 intern-vg -wi-a-----  <7,87g                                                    
root   usb-vg    -wi-ao----  48,65g                                                    
swap_1 usb-vg    -wi-ao----   7,87g
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should note that at the time of this writing, Debian 10 is still in `testing` state, so there may be rough edges here and there.

My guess would be that the Debian installer had no clue that the second installation was going to be on a removable drive, and overwrote the first installation's copy of GRUB on your EFI System Partition (ESP) with one configured to boot from the USB device.

To fix, you would have to do two things, in any order:

1.) You should ensure that the USB-based installation is bootable on its own, i.e. the USB drive should include a FAT32 partition containing a copy of the bootloader at `\EFI\boot\bootx64.efi`. That is what makes a removable USB bootable in the UEFI sense.

2.) To fix the bootloader of the installation on the internal HDD, you could boot into the USB-based installation, then mount the partition(s) of the internal HDD-based installation and chroot into that installation.

Your `fdisk -l` output indicates that there is probably LVM in use too.

Based on your `fdisk -l` output, this should be the beginning of the commands required. Note that all this should be run as root, so first use either `su -` and enter the root password, or `sudo -i` and enter your own password, to become root.

```
# mkdir /mnt/hddsystem

# cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/sda3 sda3_crypt
<the above command will ask you the encryption passphrase of the HDD installation.
If successful, then /dev/mapper/sda3_crypt should now exist>

# vgscan
<this detects the LVM volume group within the encrypted container of the HDD installation>

# lvs
<this displays all the detected LVM logical volumes and their names>

# vgchange -ay intern-vg
# mount /dev/mapper/intern--vg-root /mnt/hddsystem

<if successful, directories like /mnt/hddsystem/dev, /mnt/hddsystem/proc, /mnt/hddsystem/sys 
should be visible and empty at this point. Other directories should be visible under /mnt/hddsystem too.>

# mount /dev/sda2 /mnt/hddsystem/boot
# mount /dev/sda1 /mnt/hddsystem/boot/efi
```

At this point, it might be easy to fix the boot of the USB system too, by just copying the version of GRUB that looks for USB media to boot actually onto the USB, before we overwrite it on the HDD.

```
# mkdir /mnt/usb-esp
# mount /dev/sdb1 /mnt/usb-esp
# mkdir -p /mnt/usb-esp/EFI/boot
# cp -r /mnt/hddsystem/boot/efi/EFI/debian /mnt/usb-esp/EFI/
# cp /mnt/usb-esp/EFI/debian/grubx64.efi /mnt/usb-esp/EFI/boot/
# cp /mnt/hddsystem/boot/efi/EFI/debian/shimx64.efi /mnt/usb-esp/EFI/boot/bootx64.efi
# umount /mnt/usb-esp
```

Back to fixing the HDD installation...

```
# mount -o bind /dev /mnt/hddsystem/dev
# mount -o bind /proc /mnt/hddsystem/proc
# mount -o bind /sys /mnt/hddsystem/sys
<these commands are preparations for the following chroot command, mounting all the necessary real and virtual filesystems so that the inactive HDD-based installation can be used like an active, running system.>

# chroot /mnt/hddsystem /bin/bash
<this command transitions us to the HDD-based environment; from this point onwards, for this shell session only, /mnt/hddsystem is /.>

# grub-install /dev/sda1
# update-grub 
<these two commands to fix the bootloader are what all the preparations above were for.>
```

Comment: thank you.mount /dev/sdb1 /mnt/hddsystem

Comment: thank you.mount /dev/sdb1 /mnt/hddsystem        sdb1 for wat is that.    the third line with dev at last didnt work... i forgott to say both hdd usb are full hd encrypted. during inatallation grub installs automatically without asking.  shoud i mount encrypted partition to fix it if yes can u give me all commands again.  otherway i plan to go for debian9 an then upgrad to 10

Comment: That complicates things a bit. Please edit your question and add the output of `fdisk -l` command (you'll need to run it as root), so that I can identify the correct disk devices to use. Instead of `mount /dev/sdb1 /mnt/hddsystem` you would need two steps like `cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/<your encrypted partition> hddroot`, then `mount /dev/mapper/hddroot /mnt/hddsystem`, then you might be able to continue as above.

Comment: ok , pleas giv me then all needed commands for test . otherways i switch to debian9 . as  i said .when hdd works then usb not when usb fixed then hdd not

Comment: question has been edited

Comment: Answer edited too. If I guessed the name of the LVM volume group on the HDD correctly, these commands should do it; but if the name of the volume group is something other than `debian-vg`, please post the output of the `lvs` command at the indicated point, and I'll edit the actual details into my answer.

Comment: Thank you very much for your helpful answer.
I made your importent steps .I finally fixed it to boot from HDD . and i can see USB entry in boot manager too . Never seen the entry there before .

Now when i select USB . it says vmlinuzxxxxx has invalid signature. then i disabled secure boot and it boots too.

but i prefer to enable secure boot

Comment: Enabling Secure Boot with Debian used to be tricky in Debian 9; I have not yet investigated that in Debian 10, although I understand things have improved somewhat. Anyway, that would be definitely worth a separate question; perhaps someone else can help with that?

Comment: debian 10 supports uefi secure boot . i mean why hdd boots in secure boot . the usb not

Comment: Is there a `shim.efi`, `shimx64.efi` or something like that in `/boot/efi/EFI/debian` directory? Then that is the reason: for the USB, you would need to rename the USB's `<ESP filesystem mountpoint>/EFI/boot/bootx64.efi` back to `<ESP filesystem mountpoint>/EFI/boot/grubx64.efi`, then copy and rename the `shim.efi` to `<ESP filesystem mountpoint>/EFI/boot/bootx64.efi` on the USB. The shim supports Secure Boot and will expect the `grubx64.efi` in the same directory and will automatically run it.

Comment: (You may have noticed I also edited your question to format the command outputs as "code", so they'll be more easily readable.)

Comment: in bios when i select the option select uefi file as trusted for executing ..there are 2 folder USB and  HDD each folder has shim x grub64 etc .. when i select grub64x from USB folder it says already exist .i  Check it again. how would you rename and copy ? im new to Linux sorry

Comment: Assuming your USB will again appear as `/dev/sdb` in Linux. The following commands should be all run as root: `mount /dev/sdb1 /mnt`, `mv /mnt/EFI/boot/bootx64.efi /mnt/EFI/boot/grubx64.efi`, `cp /boot/efi/EFI/debian/shimx64.efi /mnt/EFI/boot/bootx64.efi`, then `umount /mnt`.

Comment: i did and perfect now both usb hdd reboot with SB enabled ! i see another entry in bios boot manager names usb linux .the old can boot in sb . how can i delet uneeded entries

Comment: ok i found efibootmgr . . all problem solved thank you again .very helpful

Comment: I think the option `--force-extra-removable` of `grub-install` is doing a part of what you're doing in your answer: have the extra entry that doesn't depend on the EFI firmware content.